# HTML5 audio streaming several files

Tags: html, audio, mp3

I've developed an ASP.NET web site which uses HTMl5 for playing audio files (Mp3). This application reads a book, page by page, in each page I have several audio files. Currently I'm loading each file just after the last file is finished, so there's a (sometimes long and annoying) lag between files (each file is in fact a sentence in the page). How can I develop my user experience? User can select from 3 different qualities, but I'm thinking of a streaming technique that helps me speed up the loading process, for instance when the first sentence is being played, the 2nd sentence is being loaded. How can I achieve it? Also I can use multiple Audio objects (in fact one object for each audio file), and then load these files one by one and meanwhile start playing the files right after the first file is being loaded (multiprocessing in the JavasScript? web workers?) Which one is better? Have you any suggestion? Is there any sample showing this process in action?